# Fasting on the thought of period

Tags: sawm, menses

Assalamualykum....I was unsure if I got my periods but still fasted cause I was unsure and turns out I was not mensturating! So will my fast be accepted ? Do I have to fast again ?please ans !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of niyyah (intention).
If you made the intention to fast Ramadan at the beginning of the month there shouldn't be an issue (not all madhhabs regard this as acceptable). But if you made a day by day intention the  matter could turn out somewhat complex because having doubts may have effects on the validity of an act.

Answer (score -5):

There is not a single proof that the fast of a menstruating woman is not accepted. So do not worry about that.